# How to remove hover effect on selected row?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I changed the .k-state-selected to a different color, works fine. However when I hover over the selected row the hover color is blue.
I have tried

`.k-grid tr:hover{
      background:transparent;
    }`

and that works fine for rows that are not selected, but not for the selected row. 
Essentially I need to remove the hover effect on a selected row and can't figure it out

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      field: "age"
    }
  ],
  dataSource: [{
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: 30
    },
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      age: 33
    }
  ],
  selectable: "row"
});
```

```css
.k-grid .k-state-selected {
  background: #ec971f;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Comment: check my answer ! best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```js
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [{
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      field: "age"
    }
  ],
  dataSource: [{
      name: "Jane Doe",
      age: 30
    },
    {
      name: "John Doe",
      age: 33
    }
  ],
  selectable: "row"
});
```

```css
.k-grid .k-state-selected {
  background: #ec971f;
}

.k-grid .k-state-selected:hover {
  background:  #ec971f!important;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2019.3.1023/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.k-grid tr:hover` doesn't work because of the rules of CSS specificity. In other words, `.k-grid .k-state-selected` is more specific than `.k-grid tr:hover`.

`.k-grid .k-state-selected:hover` should work for you.

[Example](https://codepen.io/majestic84/pen/ExayQaZ)